# Can not use seession laravel

Tags: laravel

I initialize session('idUser') on successful login. But it is always null when using http get.And Auth::id() is always null as well.

```
class CartService {
    public function getAll($orderBys = [],  $limit = 2) {
        $idCurrent = session('idUser'); // => null
        //$idCurrent = Auth::id(); => null

        $query = Cart::query()  -> where('user_id',$idCurrent);
        if($orderBys){
            $query->orderBy($orderBys['column'], $orderBys['sort']);
        }
        return $query-> paginate($limit);
    }
}

  //Call API (127.0.0.1:8000/api/cart)
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $carts = Http::get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/cart");
    $carts =  json_decode($carts, true);
    $cartArr = $carts['cartArr'];

    //convert 
    $cart = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < count($cartArr); $i++)
    {
        $object = new Cart();
        foreach ($cartArr[$i] as $key => $value)
        {
            $object->$key = $value;
        }
        array_push($cart,$object);  
    } 
    dd($cart);  // => result = []
}
```

Comment: Does using ```Auth::user()->id``` instead of ```Auth::id()``` return null as well?

Comment: Auth::user() -> id is also null

Comment: To get the variable  `Session::get('idUser');`,  To store data`Session::put('idUser', $value);`

Comment: Everything works fine, but when using http get Auth and Session are always empty. The problem is still unresolved. Whether I used ```Auth::loginUsingId($id);``` when logging in

Comment: Whether "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/cart" works fine.

Comment: Here's what you need to do [Laravel's API Authentication Services](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#laravels-api-authentication-services)

Comment: @Arash why does he need Passport or Sanctum? Or are you referencing the wrong thing?

Comment: @PhạmTiếnLong it sounds like youre working around the default authentication workings. If you set it up from the defaults, you should have a session for each user (even guests). If you then login, you should have `Auth::user()`/`Auth::id()` etc available. If this doesnt work for you, I suggest reviewing the default settings here: https://github.com/laravel/laravel

Comment: yes, I'm using Sanctum, and set it all up according to the instructions at "https://github.com/anil-sidhu/laravel-sanctum", not sure if something is wrong here.